# How to force mongo db $or query to check for first provided value first and fall only back to second if not found?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have a mongo db with the following documents in a collection:

```
{'foo' : 1, 'bar' : 'asd'}
{'foo' : 2, 'bar' : 'some-existing-name'}
...
{'foo' : 999999, 'bar' : 'some random string'}
```

I have added unique indexes for `foo` and `bar`.

Usecase:
I want to run a query where I would like to fetch one item by either `foo` or `bar`. I would like to always receive the item if it the proper value of `foo` is found, only fallback to an object matching the `bar` attribute if nothing matched `foo`.

```py
mycollection.find_one(
            {'$or': [{'foo': 999999},
                     {'bar': 'some-exising-name'}]})
```

The expected output would be for me to get the following docuent:
`{'foo' : 999999, 'bar' : 'some random string'}`

But based on my tests, mongo returns
`{'foo' : 2, 'bar' : 'some-existing-name'}` instead. Is it possible to keep it to one query, and still force the returned value to first try to match `foo` and not return the first encountered `bar`?

Answer (score 1):

You could add an index like this:

```
{
    "foo" : 1,
    "bar" : 1
}
```

The DB engine should be able to utilize the index and having `foo` in higher precedence when searching